# Connecting maps

Tags: navigation, mapping, turtlebot2, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using a turtlebot2 and ROS Hydro.
I want to use it to map a large area (whole floor of a building) so I would like to know if it's possible to build different maps (one for each room/corridor) and connect all of them afterwards.
Searching for similar questions I've find some people recommending the use of mapstitch. I haven't tried it yet, but I'm not sure if it is suitable for my application. In the other topics it has been used to merge maps built by different robots, but of the same environment.

Could someone point me some directions? I'm new to ROS and it would help me save lots of time if I knew which tools are appropriate for my application.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187855/connecting-maps/) by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2014-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

mapstitch looks like a good place to start. I suspect it relies heavily on overlap between the maps it's trying to merge, in order to automatically determine the alignment between maps. If you'd like to use it, you should make sure that the map pieces you make have a significant amount of overlap.

The other alternative here is to simply use an image editor to merge your maps by hand. Map files are just pnm image files, which can be opened and edited in an image editor such as gimp or photoshop.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on 2014-07-27**:
Thanks for the tips!